# Replacing a light switch with a dimmable one

Tags: electrical, wiring, dimmer-switch

I live in an old (1950’s) duplex. I purchased a new light switch (dimmable) to install. I took off the old plate etc to do the work and when I opened it up it’s a bit of a mess in there.

There are two light switches together on the plate. One is for my light on the balcony and the other for my dinning room light. They are both single pole. The patio light wire was attached the other from the hot to the screw of the other.

Should I just wire this as it was or change this up completely?
[image: Lightswitch]

Comment: If it was working before, what is the question

Answer (score 3):

It is not uncommon for 2 switches to share a hot lead from one to the other.
This worked for you before, and while the wiring is old, it looks as if it is still viable. You should be ok.

The wire attached to the balcony light switch should transfer hot to the balcony switch from the new dimmer. Attach it to the top screw of the dimmer. ( top or bottom doesn't matter, but we will use the top for convenience.)

You need to find which of the 2 remaining wires is the hot lead.

That lead gets pushed into the back of the dimmer next to that top screw. ( I know I said not to use the "Back stabs" and it is not the perfect way but it will work)

The remaining wire should be the lead to the dinning room light.  It goes on the bottom screw of the dimmer.

That should make both light work.

Comment: Thank you! I put the switch in with everything back as it was and saw tiny sparks. I cut the power again and will see what I did wrong. Maybe the hot wasn't tight enough? Also the dimming part of the light didn't work.

Comment: If you are saying that you completed attaching all the wires and saw sparks when working the switches, the most likely cause is the wires not being tight under the screws. ( DO NOT use the  "back stab" holes in the back of the switches.    For the lack of dimmer control, are you trying to dim LED bulbs or incandescent? LEDs require special dimmers and they have to be grounded and some need a neutral as well.

Comment: oh! I used the tabs since that is how it was when I took off the old one. If I don't, where do I put the two wires going in? As I mentioned, the second switch was connected to the hot screw. I have CFL bulbs in the fixture now. This is the switch that I purchased Eaton Universal Sliding Dimmer - White - 600-watt - 120-volt

Comment: Take the wires out of the "back stabs" and attach them to the screws that are next to the "backstab" holes.  ( You must put a "hook" in the wire to be under the screw.  "As I mentioned, the second switch was connected to the hot screw"...does that mean that the second switch was 3way?  Or are you saying the Hot lead was connected to that switches screw and then there was a wire from the "backstab" to your other switch, (now the dimmer) ?

Comment: No it’s not a three way. There are two switches in the plate - one for my overhead light in dinning room, the other for my outside light over my balcony. Pic enclosed in the balcony one, which was attached to the hot screw of the dining room switch. If you take a look at the pic I posted I tried to capture the wire from the balcony switch. That is the one that was connected to the hot screw on the DR light switch. I hope I am making sense!

Comment: So the balcony switch had a wire going to the dinning room switch (That was the shared hot. That must be the same for the new dimmer. Then the 2nd screw on the dimmer goes to the dinning room light.  That should be the connection.

Comment: And the third wire? When I opened it up, the dining room had two wires going into the tabs, and the screw being used by the balcony light.

Comment: Useful information.  I assume you don't have a voltage tester or noncontact tester or any extra cable....so do you know which wire came from the balcony light?  Does the balcony light still work?

Comment: I was going to buy one tomorrow - figured it would come in handy as I am embarking on my DIY renovations (was going to get Klein NCVT-3P).  The wire that came from the balcony is the one sticking up in the photo - that is the switch for the balcony. Nothing works at the moment since I cut the power.  It didn’t work when I connected it up since I hadn’t tightened the screw around the wire properly - but I assume it would?